# what does column represent in tfidf matrix?

Tags: python, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to understand the result of TF-IDF matrix. Here is the code I am using.

```
sen1 = TextBlob("This is a sample")
d1 = sen1.words
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfvectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf= TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=identity_tokenizer, stop_words='english', lowercase=False)    
tf = tfidf.fit_transform(d1).todense()
```

So, I am trying to understand the tf matrix thus obtained. Following is the attached picture of the tf matrix.[image]

Could someone please help me why do I have 7 columns for a corpus of 4 words? Do the rows represent the number of words.

From what I study in different resources is "The result is a matrix of tf-idf scores with one row per document and as many columns as there are different words in the dataset." But I am not being able to validate it from the result I obtain here.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your result. The d1 variable is ['This', 'is', 'a', 'sample'].
And this means sklearn interprets this as 4 documents and then uses characters as the words.

You can check like this.

> tf = tfidf.fit(d1)
>
> tf.get_feature_names()
>
> ['T', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'm','p', 's']